# Python Selenium multiple button message box

Tags: python, selenium, alert, messagebox

How can I press the yes button on a 3 button message box using python. my code below can only handle alert box.

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

see screenshot of the message box I get:

[image]

**Update:
here is the source code of the popup msg:

```
function preSubmit() {
    var f = getForm();
    var confMsg= ("Do you want to set the WUC\'\s Scheduled End Date to this PCA\'\s Requested PC Date of "+f.pcAdj.value+" ?");
    var title = 'Confirm';
    test = vbMsg(confMsg, title);

    if(test == 6){
        f.adjPCDateFlag.value = true;   
        f.submitpca.value = true ;
        f.command.value = "doWucPcaView";
        doSubmit(f);
    }
    else if(test == 7){
        f.adjPCDateFlag.value = false;
        f.submitpca.value = true ;
        doSubmit(f);
    }
}
```

another issue I have is that this needs to open in firefox, and i am unable to press this and get the popup message

Comment: once you switched to the alert box, you should find the Yes button and then click on it. Something like : alert = driver.switch_to_alert() button = alert.find_element_by_.... button.click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the alert you have received is a VB Script based pop-up and as far as I am aware "**alert**" in Selenium handles Javascript related pop-ups.

In order to handle these kind of .net based alerts you have to either make use of **Autoit** or **Winnium**.

Comment: could i send the enter button maybe?

Comment: you could do that but the windows has to be in focus at that time. correct?

Comment: yes, the pop up will be in focus at that time.. when sending the enter command, do i need to specify the element i am sending this to? in which case what is it? pls

Comment: Yes @KrishnaKokila  I just changed from Firefox to ie

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching from Firefox to IE. then used the code below
as firefox was not able to execute the vb script so no message was popping up.

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```